# Bootstrap custom layout right column wrapping under left column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone please help me out with my bootstrap layout.

Before the browser breakpoint hits 980px the right column wraps underneath the left column, but I want it to stay in its position though with no wrapping happening.

The thing is I also require the left column to have a fixed width and the right column to not have a fixed width but possibly be able to decrease the widths of the elements in my form so they dont overlap each other when the browser/viewport is resized (My horizontal form has more elements within the same lines, but I omitted some of these overlapping elements to remain minimal for the the sake of this question).

I dont think my form-group elements have the correct col sizes...

I wish to use media queries to get around this (mine currently are working a little), so if anyone can play in my codepen that would be very helpful :)

I have a link you can modify my layout here:
http://codepen.io/krystyna93/pen/GZzqrq

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
/* General styles */

.container {
  background-color: #bbb;
  font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
  width: 1530px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Large desktop */

@media and screen (max-width: 1590px) {
  .container {
    width: auto;
  }
}
@media and screen (min-width: 981px) and (max-width: 1530px) {
  .accordion.sidebar {
    width: 230px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 980px) {
  .accordion.sidebar {
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
  }
}
.col-md-10 {
  border-left: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container .row.header {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #fff
}
.container .row.header h1 {
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
}
h3 {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
h3.inner {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
h4 {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.headers {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.headers h1 {
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.headers p {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/* ****** NAVIGATION SIDEBAR ********
**********************************
*/

.accordion.sidebar {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.panel {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  border: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400
}
.panel-group {
  border-radius: 0; //box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #074f68; border: 0; background-color: #fff}
  .panel-heading h4.panel-title {
    border-radius: 0; //box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #074f68; border: 0; background-color: #fff;}
    .panel-heading h4.panel-title a: link {
      margin-left: 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px
    }
    .panel-heading h4.panel-title a:active {
      color: #fff
    }
    .panel-heading h4.panel-title a:hover {
      color: #FF5500
    }
    .panel-group .panel+.panel {
      margin-top: 0px !important;
      border-top: 1px solid #ccc
    }
    .panel.panel-default.custom .panel-heading {
      background: #fff;
      color: #000;
      border-color: #fff
    }
    .panel-body {
      /* padding-top: 2px !important; padding-bottom: 0px !important; */
      padding: 0px !important;
      border: 0
    }
    .panel-body ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0
    }
    .panel-body ul li {
      padding: 10px 0 !important;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
      font-size: 1.4em
    }
    .panel-body ul li:last-child {
      border-bottom: 0
    }
    .panel-body ul a {
      color: #1f1f1f
    }
    .panel-body ul li a:link {
      margin-left: 40px !important;
      color: #1f1f1f
    }
    .panel-body ul li a:active {
      color: #fff
    }
    .panel-body ul li a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #FF5500
    }
    #collapseOne.panel-collapse,
    #collapseTwo.panel-collapse,
    #collapseThree.panel-collapse {
      border: 0 !important;
      padding: 0
    }
    .panel-heading.collapsed {
      background-color: #222222
    }
    /* ******** FORM STYLING ***********
************************************
*/
    .form-horizontal .form-group .custom-label {
      text-align: left;
      margin-top: -10px;
      font-size: 22px;
      font-weight: normal;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .form-horizontal .form-group .form-control {
      background-color: #4d4d4d;
      border-color: #4d4d4d;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .form-horizontal .form-group .input-text {
      font-size: 1.3em;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .form-horizontal .form-group .form-control:hover {
      background-color: #34383C;
      border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
    }
    .form-horizontal .form-group .form-control:focus {
      border: 1px solid #FF5500;
    }
    /* DROPDOWN MENU STYLING */
    /* OPTIONAL FOR DROPDOWN CARET */
    .dropdown-toggle .caret {
      /* position: absolute; right: 12px; top: calc(50% - 2px); */
      background-image: url('arr.jpg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      position: absolute;
      right: 12px;
      top: calc(50% - 2px);
    }
    .form-group.social .col-md-2 {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 200px;
    }
    .form-group.social .col-md-2 .fa-instagram,
    .form-group.social .col-md-2 .fa-twitter {
      font-size: 1.1em;
      padding: 0 5px 0 20px;
    }
    .changePswrd {
      padding: 3px 0 0 12px;
    }
    .changePswrd a:link {
      font-family: 'Lato', verdana, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.3em;
      color: #fff;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .changePswrd a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #FF5500;
    }
    .form-group .placeholder-img.col-md-2 {
      height: 320px;
      width: 230px;
      background-color: #4d4d4d;
      margin: 0 20px;
    }
    .form-group .placeholder-img-thumb {
      height: 320px;
    }
    .form-group .placeholder-img-thumb .thumb-img {
      text-align: center;
      width: 130px;
    }
    .form-group .placeholder-img-thumb .circle {
      width: 130px;
      height: 130px;
      background: #4d4d4d;
      -moz-border-radius: 100px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
      border-radius: 100px;
    }
    .form-group .placeholder-img-thumb .caption {
      width: 100%;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .form-group .profile-photo-help.col-md-4 {
      width: 200px;
    }
    .form-group .profile-photo-help {
      width: 280px;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .form-group .profile-photo-help p {} .form-group .profile-photo-help a:link {
      color: #FF5500;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .form-group .profile-photo-help a:hover {
      color: #fff;
    }
    .form-group .create-card-btn .glyphicon-plus {
      font-size: 0.9em;
      padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    }
    .form-group .input-group.date span.input-group-addon {
      background-color: #4d4d4d;
      color: #fff;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border-color: none;
    }
    .form-group .input-group.date .form-control.date {
      font-size: 1.2em;
    }
    .form-group .strength-delete-btn .glyphicon-minus {
      font-size: 0.9em;
      padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    }
    /*  SUBMISSION BUTTONS */
    .submission {
      background-color: #333333;
      border-top: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
      margin-top: 80px;
      padding-top: 40px;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .submission button {
      border-radius: 3px;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      border: none;
    }
    .submission .glyphicon-remove-circle,
    .submission .glyphicon-ok-circle {
      font-size: 1.6em;
      font-weight: 400;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding: 0 5px;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .submission .btn-cancel {
      margin-right: 20px;
      background-color: #4d4d4d;
    }
    .submission .btn-save {
      background-color: #aaa;
    }
    .submission .action-btns .btn-primary:hover,
    .submission .action-btns .btn-primary.outline:focus,
    .btn-primary:active {
      color: #33a6cc;
      border-color: #fff;
    }
    .submission .action-btns .btn-primary:active,
    .submission .action-btns .btn-primary.active {
      border-color: #007299;
      color: #007299;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    .btn.outline {
      background: none;
      padding: 12px 22px;
    }
    .btn.outline.upload {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
    }
    .btn.outline.football {
      background: none;
      padding: 5px 22px;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .btn.outline.create-card-btn {
      background: none;
      padding: 5px 22px;
    }
    .btn.outline.sizing-guide-btn {
      background: none;
      padding: 5px 22px;
    }
    .btn.outline.strength-delete-btn {
      background: none;
      padding: 5px 22px;
      width: 100%
    }
    .btn.outline.add-result-btn {
      background: none;
      padding: 5px 22px;
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .btn-primary.outline {
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      color: #fff;
      font-family: 'Lato', verdana, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.1em;
    }
    .btn-primary.outline.strength-delete-btn {
      border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
      color: #4d4d4d;
    }
    .btn-primary.outline:hover,
    .btn-primary.outline:focus,
    .btn-primary.outline:active,
    .btn-primary.outline.active,
    .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
      color: #FF5500;
      border-color: #F47929;
    }
    .btn-primary.outline:active,
    .btn-primary.outline.active {
      border-color: #007299;
      color: #007299;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    /* CUSTOM SUBMISSION BTN VALUES */
    .btn-primary {
      padding: 14px 24px;
      border: 0 none;
    }
    .btn:focus,
    .btn:active:focus,
    .btn.active:focus {
      outline: 0 none;
    }
```

```html
<head>
  <title>layout</title>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row header">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 accordion sidebar">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          <div class="panel panel-default custom">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="account2.html" href="#collapseOne"> Link 1 </a>
     </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                    <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                      <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default custom">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"  data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseTwo">Title 2</a>
     </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                    <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                      <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                        <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                          <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default custom">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseThree">Title 3</a>
     </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                    <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                      <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-default custom">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseFive">Title 4</a>
     </h4>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-default custom">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseSix">Title 5
      </a>
      </h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of sidebar -->
      </div>
      <!-- end of row -->

      <div class="container load">
        <div class="col-lg-10">

          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <h2>Page Title</h2>
                <div class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/details" method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <h3 class="inner">General</h3>
                    <label for="title" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="" placeholder="title" focus>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="title" placeholder="title">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="title" placeholder="title">
                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="headers">
                    <h3>Information</h3>
                    <p>
                      Info titletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitle</br>
                      titletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitle
                    </p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <h3 class="inner">Address</h3>
                    <label for="unit" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="title" placeholder="1">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="streetNo" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="title" placeholder="25">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="streetName" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="streetName" placeholder="title">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="suburb" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="suburb" placeholder="title">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="zip" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="zip" placeholder="title">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="state" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="state" placeholder="title">
                    </div>
                  </div>



                  <div class="headers">
                    <h3>Social Networks</h3>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group social">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                      <label for="instagram" class="control-label custom-label"><span><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></span> Instagram</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="instagram-input" placeholder="instagramhandle">
                    </div>



                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group social">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                      <label for="twitter" class="control-label custom-label"><span><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span> Twitter</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="twitter-input" placeholder="twitterhandle">
                    </div>


                  </div>

                  <div class="row submission">
                    <div class="form-group btn-block">
                      <div class="pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-cancel ">Cancel changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-save">Save changes</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of form -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of row -->
            <!-- </div> end of container -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end of container -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {   
 background-color: #ccc;
}

/* General styles */
.container { background-color: #bbb; font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif; width: 1530px; margin: 0 auto; }

/* Large desktop */
  @media and screen (max-width: 1590px) {
   .container {width: auto;}
  }
  @media and screen (min-width: 981px) and (max-width: 1530px){
      .accordion.sidebar {width: 230px;
            }
}

        @media and screen(max-width: 980px) {
         
            
        } 
 
.col-md-10{ border-left: 1px solid #4d4d4d; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.container .row.header{ color: #fff; border-bottom: 6px solid #fff }
.container .row.header h1 { padding: 30px 0; font-size: 3.5em;  font-weight: 300; }

h2 { color: #fff; font-size: 32px; }
h3 {color: #ccc; font-size: 30px; padding-bottom: 10px; } 
h3.inner { padding-left: 15px;}
h4 {color: #ccc; font-size: 22px; }

.headers { border-top: 1px solid #ccc; margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom:30px;}
.headers h1 { padding: 20px 0 0 0; }
.headers p {font-size: 1.6em; color: #fff; padding: 0 0 10px 0; margin: 0;}
/* ****** NAVIGATION SIDEBAR ********
**********************************
*/
.accordion.sidebar { padding: 0; background-color: #fff;}
.panel {border-radius: 0 !important; border: 0; font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400}
.panel-group {border-radius: 0; //box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #074f68; border: 0; background-color: #fff}
.panel-heading h4.panel-title {border-radius: 0; //box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #074f68; border: 0; background-color: #fff;}

.panel-heading h4.panel-title a:link { margin-left: 10px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px}
.panel-heading h4.panel-title a:active {color: #fff }
.panel-heading h4.panel-title a:hover {color: #FF5500}

.panel-group .panel+.panel {margin-top: 0px !important; border-top: 1px solid #ccc}
.panel.panel-default.custom .panel-heading { background: #fff; color: #000; border-color: #fff }

.panel-body {/* padding-top: 2px !important; padding-bottom: 0px !important; */ padding: 0px !important; border: 0 }
.panel-body ul { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
.panel-body ul li { padding: 10px 0 !important; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; font-size: 1.4em}
.panel-body ul li:last-child {border-bottom: 0}

.panel-body ul a { color: #1f1f1f}
.panel-body ul li a:link { margin-left: 40px !important; color: #1f1f1f}
.panel-body ul li a:active {color: #fff}
.panel-body ul li a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: #FF5500 }

#collapseOne.panel-collapse,
#collapseTwo.panel-collapse,
#collapseThree.panel-collapse { border: 0 !important; padding: 0}

.panel-heading.collapsed { background-color: #222222} 

/* ******** FORM STYLING ***********
************************************
*/


.form-horizontal .form-group .custom-label{ text-align: left; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 22px; font-weight: normal; color: #fff; }
.form-horizontal .form-group .form-control { background-color: #4d4d4d; border-color: #4d4d4d; color: #fff;   border-radius: 3px;}
.form-horizontal .form-group .input-text { font-size: 1.3em; color: #fff;}
.form-horizontal .form-group .form-control:hover { background-color: #34383C; border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;}
.form-horizontal .form-group .form-control:focus { border: 1px solid #FF5500; }

/* DROPDOWN MENU STYLING */

/* OPTIONAL FOR DROPDOWN CARET */
.dropdown-toggle .caret { /* position: absolute; right: 12px; top: calc(50% - 2px); */ background-image: url('arr.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; right: 12px; top: calc(50% - 2px);}

.form-group.social .col-md-2 { padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 200px;}
.form-group.social .col-md-2  .fa-instagram, .form-group.social .col-md-2  .fa-twitter { font-size: 1.1em; padding: 0 5px 0 20px;}

.changePswrd {padding: 3px 0 0 12px;}
.changePswrd a:link{ font-family: 'Lato', verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 1.3em; color: #fff; display: inline-block; }
.changePswrd a:hover{ text-decoration: none; color: #FF5500;  }

.form-group .placeholder-img.col-md-2{ height: 320px; width: 230px; background-color: #4d4d4d; margin: 0 20px;}
.form-group .placeholder-img-thumb { height: 320px;}
.form-group .placeholder-img-thumb .thumb-img { text-align: center; width: 130px;}
.form-group .placeholder-img-thumb .circle { width: 130px; height: 130px; background: #4d4d4d; -moz-border-radius: 100px; -webkit-border-radius: 100px; border-radius: 100px; }
.form-group .placeholder-img-thumb .caption { width: 100%; color: #fff;}

.form-group .profile-photo-help.col-md-4 { width: 200px;}
.form-group .profile-photo-help { width: 280px; color: #fff;}
.form-group .profile-photo-help p {}
.form-group .profile-photo-help a:link { color: #FF5500; text-decoration: none; }
.form-group .profile-photo-help a:hover { color: #fff; }
.form-group .create-card-btn .glyphicon-plus { font-size: 0.9em; padding: 0 10px 0 0;}

.form-group .input-group.date span.input-group-addon { background-color: #4d4d4d; color: #fff; border: none; border-radius: 3px; border-color: none;}
.form-group .input-group.date .form-control.date { font-size: 1.2em;}
.form-group .strength-delete-btn .glyphicon-minus { font-size: 0.9em; padding: 0 5px 0 0;}





/*  SUBMISSION BUTTONS */
.submission {  background-color: #333333; border-top: 1px solid #4d4d4d; margin-top: 80px; padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 40px;}
.submission button{  border-radius: 3px; font-size: 1.5em; border: none;}
.submission .glyphicon-remove-circle, .submission .glyphicon-ok-circle {font-size: 1.6em; font-weight: 400; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0 5px; color: #fff;}
.submission .btn-cancel {margin-right: 20px; background-color: #4d4d4d;}
.submission .btn-save {background-color: #aaa; }

.submission .action-btns .btn-primary:hover, .submission .action-btns .btn-primary.outline:focus, .btn-primary:active { color: #33a6cc; border-color: #fff; } 
.submission .action-btns .btn-primary:active, .submission .action-btns .btn-primary.active { border-color: #007299; color: #007299; box-shadow: none; } 


.btn.outline { background: none; padding: 12px 22px; }
.btn.outline.upload { position: absolute; bottom: 0; padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px; }
.btn.outline.football { background: none; padding: 5px 22px; margin-right: 20px;} 
.btn.outline.create-card-btn {background: none; padding: 5px 22px; }
.btn.outline.sizing-guide-btn { background: none; padding: 5px 22px; }
.btn.outline.strength-delete-btn { background: none; padding: 5px 22px; width: 100%}
.btn.outline.add-result-btn { background: none; padding: 5px 22px; margin-top: 15px;}

.btn-primary.outline { border: 1px solid #fff; color: #fff; font-family: 'Lato', verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 1.1em;} 
.btn-primary.outline.strength-delete-btn { border: 1px solid #4d4d4d; color: #4d4d4d;} 
.btn-primary.outline:hover, .btn-primary.outline:focus, .btn-primary.outline:active, .btn-primary.outline.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary { color: #FF5500; border-color: #F47929; } 
.btn-primary.outline:active, .btn-primary.outline.active { border-color: #007299; color: #007299; box-shadow: none; } 

/* CUSTOM SUBMISSION BTN VALUES */

.btn-primary { padding: 14px 24px; border: 0 none; } 
.btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn.active:focus { outline: 0 none; }
```

```html
 <head>
  <title>CUSTOM LAYOUT</title>
  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom-styles.css" />
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <!--  **********************************
    following functionality for the accordion referencing to load individual 
    body of parent links 
   ************************************
  --> 
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- script for navigation load of individual body sections -->
  <script src="accordion.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
  
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row header">
      <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 accordion sidebar">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default custom">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="account2.html" href="#collapseOne">
         Link 1
         </a>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
         <div class="panel-body">
         <ul class="list-unstyled">
         <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
         <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
         <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
         </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default custom">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"  data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseTwo">
         Title 2
         </a>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body">
         <ul class="list-unstyled">
         <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
         <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
         <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
         <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
         <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
         </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default custom">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseThree">
         Title 3
         </a>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body">
         <ul class="list-unstyled">
         <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
         <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
         <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
         </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="panel panel-default custom">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseFive">
         Title 4
         </a>
         </h4>
      </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="panel panel-default custom">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseSix">
         Title 5
         </a>
         </h4>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end of sidebar -->
    </div>
      <!-- end of row -->
      
     <div class="container load">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
          
          <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <h2>Page Title</h2>
      <div class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/details" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
          <h3 class="inner">General</h3>
          <label for="title" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="" placeholder="title" focus>
          </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="title" placeholder="title">
          </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="title" placeholder="title">
          </div>
          
       </div>

       <div class="headers">
        <h3>Information</h3>
        <p>
         Info titletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitle </br>
titletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitle
        </p>
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group">
        <h3 class="inner">Address</h3>
         <label for="unit" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="title" placeholder="1">
         </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="streetNo" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="title" placeholder="25">
         </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="streetName" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="streetName" placeholder="title">
         </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="suburb" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="suburb" placeholder="title">
         </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="zip" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="zip" placeholder="title">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="state" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="state" placeholder="title">
         </div>
        </div>
       
       
       
       <div class="headers">
        <h3>Social Networks</h3>
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group social">
         <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
          <label for="instagram" class="control-label custom-label"><span><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></span> Instagram</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="instagram-input" placeholder="instagramhandle">
         </div>
         
       
      
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group social">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
         <label for="twitter" class="control-label custom-label"><span><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span> Twitter</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
         <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="twitter-input" placeholder="twitterhandle">
         </div> 

       
       </div>
       
       <div class="row submission">
         <div class="form-group btn-block">
          <div class="pull-right">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-cancel ">Cancel changes</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-save">Save changes</button>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div> 
      </div> <!-- end of form -->
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end of row -->
   <!-- </div> end of container -->
    
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of container -->
```

Comment: thank you so much! however when in full browser size the width is not 1530px for my container, it seems to be using the bootstrap default width. How do I ensure it takes my custom 1530px for my container?

Comment: it seems the width for the wrapper when its at the smaller breakpoint is not 100% width with the navigation, it takes the entire width of the container, how do I fix this also??

Comment: can you help with my question just above that I have just asked, or if anyone could? Im kind of desperate to get this fixed......

Comment: I said I needed the left column to have a fixed width...plus the extra questions I have asked just above....